# SVG Inline Font-Size Property Rendering Wildly different Pixel Size than Expected

Tags: svg, font-size

I am trying to adjust the font size of my svg file directly in the svg code used inline in the html. The font-size property does respond to changes of value however the values seem to be completely different in appearance than expected.

SVG Code Here:

```html
 <svg
       
       width="167mm"
       height="17mm"
       viewBox="0 0 167 17">
    
            <text
           xml:space="preserve"
       

    style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:7.90222216px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Open Sans Condensed';-inkscape-font-specification:'Open Sans Condensed, ';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#dfddfe;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332"
           x="18.06776"
           y="21.276409"
           id="text4998-2-0"><tspan
             sodipodi:role="line"
             x="18.06776"
             y="21.276409"
             style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-family:'Open Sans Condensed';-inkscape-font-specification:'Times New Roman, ';stroke-width:0.26458332"
             id="tspan5000-5-1">1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16</tspan></text>
             </svg>
```

When I change the *"font-size"* value to *20px*, the font turns huge, something closer to what we would normally call 50px. Why do the pixel sizes seem to be different? On a related note, why is the default setting (*7.90222216px*) such a complex decimal value? When I originally made the svg file in Inkscape I set the font-size to 22.4px.

Comment: It depends on the viewBox you have. Please edit your question and add the svg element with the text

Comment: @enxaneta I hope I have added what you were looking for.

Comment: While the viewBox has a width of 167 user units (think pixels) the width of the svg element is 167mm. This is equivalent to 631px, meaning that the svg element is stretched 3.77 times. As a consequence the text is stretched too and although the font size is 7.9px it apears as if it were 7.9*3.77 = 29.783px. ALSO: as an observation The height of the viewBox is too small and part of the text will fall outside the svg canvas

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a `foreignobject` inside the svg. Inside it I added a div and styled it like any other font in the page.